# Swift variable is nil half the time

Tags: swift

I'd like to update `filterX` in accordance to the accelerometer updates, but the variable is `nil` half of the time when I build. At first I thought that it was a scope issue with `self`, but realized it would not work the other half the time.

My second guess was that it was some kind of a race condition. That didn't make sense either since the code is running synchronously, and that it should correct itself since the parent function is run every 0.1 second.

Any help is appreciated.

```
class LocationTrackingService: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = LocationTrackingService()
    private override init() {}

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    var filterX : KalmanFilter<Double>?

    func startTracking() {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()

            let location = locationManager.location!
            let XYCoord = LatLonToXY(coordinate: (location.coordinate))

            self.filterX = KalmanFilter(stateEstimatePrior: XYCoord.x, errorCovariancePrior: pow(location.horizontalAccuracy, 2))
        }

        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {


            print(self.filterX) // <-- prints object no problem


            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { data, _ in


                print(self.filterX) // <------- prints nil half the time (i.e. half of the builds)


                if let acceleration = data?.acceleration {
                    if self.filterX != nil { 
                        // do stuff
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Half of the builds? Do you mean the behavior changes from build to build?

Comment: Yes. Behavior changes from build to build; specifically sometimes it is the proper value, other times its nil.

Comment: Is your XYCoord.x non-nil when passed into your KalmanFilter when the filterX is being set to nil? How about location.horizontalAccuracy ?  If both of those look good, then try setting a local var rather than self.filterX.  If the local var can be nil too, then I'd think it must be your KalmanFilter() in error.

Answer (score 0):

Where's your `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization:)` delegate method?  You need to get authorization before proceeding to `startUpdatingLocation()`.

Comment: I excluded it for the sake of keeping the example short. All necessary authorization has been given prior to building the app. Plus the locationManager is running without a hitch.. It's the `filterX variable that is printing `nil` half the time.